# Why is it that "Member must not have @private JsDoc"?

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-closure-library, gjslint

I'm cleaning up my code with the gjslint tool from Google Closure Tools. It is reporting the following error:

```
Line 15, E:0222: Member "this._dictionary" must not have @private JsDoc
```

And this is the code:

```
/**
 * Stacker class.
 * @constructor
 * @param {frankenstein.app.Dictionary} dictionary input dictionary for stacking.
 */
frankenstein.app.Stacker = function(dictionary) {
  /** @private */ this._dictionary = dictionary;
};
```

Can somebody explain why this._dictionary must not have @private JsDoc? Thanks!

Comment: I would suspect it's because it is only "private by convention" (e.g. not private-by-closure).

Comment: What is the difference? I didn't think that any of the annotations were enforceable.

Comment: But it looks like gslint is trying ;-) Perhaps that "error" can be downgraded to a warning? Or does `@private` alter the Closure Compiler output/heuristics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Closure Linter is designed to enforce the ***[Google JavaScript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml)***. The JSDoc tag `@private` is documented as follows:

> Used in conjunction with a ***trailing underscore*** on the method or property name to indicate that the member is private. Trailing underscores may eventually be deprecated as tools are updated to enforce `@private`.

As of Closure Linter version 2.3.6, the error "Member <name> must not have @private JsDoc" will be emitted whenever a member is annotated `@private` without a trailing underscore.

This code will not emit any errors or warnings.

```javascript
/**
 * Stacker class.
 * @constructor
 * @param {frankenstein.app.Dictionary} dictionary Input dictionary for 
 *     stacking.
 */
frankenstein.app.Stacker = function(dictionary) {
  /** @private */ this.dictionary_ = dictionary;
};
```

Comment: Isn't that contradictory?! If you do put the '_' you do not get the warning, but if you do not put it, then it tells you that you should add it even though later it may become deprecated...